# Safari Browser stop js execution after window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have js code which show (fake) progress bar on button click.
than with set time out it change value of progress bar

```
 $(".quickbook-btn").click(function(){
   $(".progress").removeClass('hide')
   setTimeout(barAnim, 50);
   window.location = path
 });

 var value = 0;
 function barAnim(){
   value += 5;
   $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value );
   $(".progress-bar").text((value)+'%');
   if ( value == 10 || value == 20 || value == 30|| value == 50 || value == 75 || value == 90 ) {
     return setTimeout(barAnim, 1500);
   }
 }
```

It works perfectly in chrome, Firefox etc.

But when it comes to Safari, it stops js execution on reaching at window.location line.

I have even tested it like, letting reach progress up to 50% and than call window.location it stop execution of js instantly, although url in window.location take more than 10 seconds to complete.

Whats the issue here? why safari always sucks

Comment: It's probably not the solution, but you do miss a few `;`

Comment: yes, but testing with semicolons, still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding no proper solution, I shifted my request to ajax & on response use window.location. (But one thing is sure that Safari sucks)

```
$(".quickbook-btn").click(function(){
      $(".progress").removeClass('hide')
      setTimeout(barAnim, 50);

      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "#{path}",
      }).done(function( data ) {
        $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", 100 + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", 100 );
        $(".progress-bar").text((100)+'%');
        window.location = "#{club_quick_books_path}"
      });
    });

    var value = 0;
    function barAnim(){
        value += 5;
        $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value );
        $(".progress-bar").text((value)+'%');
        if ( value == 10 || value == 20  || value == 30|| value == 50 || value == 75 || value == 90 ) {
            return setTimeout(barAnim, 1500);
        }
        return value >= 95 || setTimeout(barAnim, 50);
    }
```